# Как сделать,чтобы в telebot,когда пользователь нажал кнопку и вёл данные,то они записывались и выводились коректно,а сейчас выводится название кнопки?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telebot

```
keyboard1 =  types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True,resize_keyboard=True)
keyboard1.row("Create zametku", "Views zametki")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def create_zam(message):
      if message.text == "Create zametku":
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите название заметки!: ")
         stringer_title = message.text
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели! \nНазвание: " + stringer_title)
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в качестве условия обновления переменной `stringer_title` ставите `message.text == "Create zametku"`. Соответственно, в переменную и может записаться только "Create zametku". После блока `if` поставьте `else`, где будете обновлять переменную, в которой хранится название заметки. Как-то так:

```
def create_zam(message):
      if message.text == "Create zametku":
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите название заметки!: ")
      else:
         stringer_title = message.text
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели! \nНазвание: " + stringer_title)
```

Comment: Ну и не забудьте, что теперь в переменную будет записываться абсолютно все, что не "Create zametku". Для такого лучше вообще использовать состояния пользователей, хранящиеся где-либо, особенно, если ботом пользоваться будет не один человек (иначе название рискует попасть в чужие руки)

Comment: Спасибо,а как теперь сднлать,чтобы после названия нужно было вести описание и они выводились по очереди?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py